Shifting a value by a specified number of cells in a row
If the value in cell A1 is input as 1Q'24, then I want $2M in Row 3, column 1Q'25 (basically after four quarters), if the value in A1 is 2Q'24 then $2M should be in Row 3, 2Q'25 column (after four quarters)














Row 1
1Q'24







Row 2
1Q'24
2Q'24
3Q'24
4Q'24
1Q'25
etc.,


Row 3
0
0
0
0
0




Tried, Offset function with no luck.

You need to fill the third row with the next formula:
A3 =IF($A$1=A2;2000000;0)

Enter the formula above into A3 and fill it to right as much as required.
